# Defining custom template for content file in local Hugo project

Tags: hugo

Running hugo locally. See attached photo of my directory structure.

Hitting `localhost:1313/directions-accomodations` in Chrome browser. The content file (red box) is loading the `single.html` template (blue box).

I want it to load a custom template. `directions.html` (*any of them*). Where do I need to put `directions.html`, OR, what value do I give the `layout` front-matter variable in `/directions-accomodations/index.md`in order to achieve this?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the layout as 
layout: "Direction-Accommodation/directions"

this will point the layout to directions.html